# Error with a JSONP code. Error: "XML can't be the whole program"

Tags: jquery, xml, jsonp

I am using the following code:

```js
function getXml(username)
{
    $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            dataType:"jsonp",
            url: "http://76.222.193.173:8080/vvmfb/users/"+username,
            success: function(jsonp)
            {
                //alert(jsonp);
            }
        });
}
getXml('farhana');
```

But it is giving me this error message:

```
XML can't be the whole program
http://76.222.193.173:8080/vvmfb/users/farhana?callback=jQuery17108919437211861222_1326137662617&_=1326137662621
</user>
Line 12
```

The XML file can be seen at:
http://76.222.193.173:8080/vvmfb/users/farhana

Any ideas, why is this happening? 
Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: XML is not JSON. In addition, JSONp is very different from even JSON.

Comment: Prepare for the inevitable "How do I convert XML into JSONP?" question, everybody.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying to receive XML with an Ajax-call that expects JSONP.

You have to decide whether to receive XML or JSONP. If it is XML that you intend to receive, then you will have to change your Ajax-call so that is expects XML as result.

Since you are specifying IP, port and the whole shebang as the URL I guess you intend do a cross-site request, and if that is the purpose why you are specifying JSONP, then you can not return XML from the server. XML is not allowed for cross-site requests due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Answer (score 2):

JSONP *must* supply a chunk of data that will be interpreted as Javascript by a `<script>` tag.  It works by exploiting the weakness in the browser security model that allows `<script>` tags to load scripts from any domain without any Cross Origin security checks.

XML isn't that.

Comment: this is the xml data:

<user>
<id>25</id>
<mdn>03212345678</mdn>
<vnotesSubId/>
<facebookId>farhana</facebookId>
<facebookUserName/>
<state>new</state>
<folders>inbox</folders>
<accessToken/>
<dateCreated>Fri Jan 06 02:41:41 PST 2012</dateCreated>
<lastUpdated>Fri Jan 06 02:41:41 PST 2012</lastUpdated>
</user>

Sorry, but i think i cannot format the code in comments, anyways, what i have understand so far is that, the xml must be wrapped in <script> tags, like this:
<script>
<user>
.....
</script>

Comment: @AamirSiddique no, it's worse than that - the script must contain a function which will be called and must then _return_ the XML, most likely as a string.  The name of that function should be in the `callback` or `jsonp` parameter supplied to the web server.